# C++ omitting `noexcept` specifier versus `noexcept(false)`, what is their precise meaning?

Tags: c++, c++11, noexcept

If I mark a function as `noexcept(false)`, or any other expression which evaluates to false, what does it means? (1) am I ensuring to the compiler that the function can throw an exception?, (2) or am I ensuring nothing about whether it can throw exceptions or not?

And lastly, if I omit the `noexcept` specifier, it is equivalent to `noexcept(false)`, or only equivalent to the (2)nd meaning stated above?

Comment: If you take `noexcept(false)` to be the opposite of `noexcept(true)`, [a reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec) answers everything.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By specifying `noexcept(true)`, you claim that the function never throws exceptions. By specifying `noexcept(false)`, or not specifying anything, you do not claim that the function never throws exceptions.

So it's basically your statement (2), but note that for the compiler, that's equivalent to your statement (1). If the compiler is not assured that the function will not throw, it must assume that it can.

The relevant bit of the standard is C++11 15.4/12:

> A function with no *exception-specification* or with an *exception-specification* of the form `noexcept(constant-expression)` where the *constant-expression* yields `false` allows all exceptions. An *exception-specification* is
>   *non-throwing* if it is of the form `throw()`, `noexcept`, or `noexcept(constant-expression)` where the *constant-expression*
>   yields `true`. A function with a non-throwing *exception-specification* does not allow any exceptions.

There are only two deviations from that rule. One is destructors—putting no exception specification on a destructor gives the destructor the same exception specification as the default-generated one would have. That is, `noexcept(true)` if and only if all functions which would be directly invoked from the default-generated destructor are `noexcept(true)`.

The other one are deallocation functions (`operator delete`)—a deallocation function without an explicit exception specification is treated as `noexcept(true)`.

Comment: @Deduplicator Changed the wording regarding the functions, but I can't seem to find a reference to constructors behaving the same. Can you provide a paragraph number?

Comment: @Deduplicator Only if it's not user-provided (i.e., implicitly declared or explicitly defaulted on first declaration). See [dcl.fct.def.default]/p2, [except.spec]/14.

Comment: You also missed deallocation functions, which are by default `noexcept(true)`.

Answer (score 9):

Omitting the `noexcept` specifier is equivalent to `noexcept(false)`, *except for destructors*, where omitting the specifier means letting the compiler deduce from the members and base classes.